# No sé cómo solucionar el error "El término 'python' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable"

Tags: python

> PS C:\Users\usuario\Documents\python> & python
> El término 'python' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.

```
En línea: 1 Carácter: 2
+ & <<<<  python
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: ¿Tenes python instalado?

Comment: que fue lo que descargaste desde visual studio code? desde ahi, no se instala python. Lo que instala ahi es una libreria para, por ejemplo, chequear el codigo, pero tenes que tener instalado python en tu sistema...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: La versión mas reciente de Python no es compatible con Windows 7, pero puedes descargar la 2.7

Comment: que version deberia descargar pra un windows 7?

Comment: deberias usar python 2.7 creo, igual si quieres probar otra version puedes usar algun compilador en la nube, como Google colab o tambien puedes instalar linex en tu computadora asi soportara python 3.x

Comment: he descargado la version 2.7  pero me sigue saliendo el mismo errpr

Comment: @angelyflorber por que debes agregarlo a las variables de sistema

Answer (score 0):

Estoy entendiendo que estas usando Visual Code y descargaste la extensión de Python, si es el caso entonces para empezar a programar te hace falta un interprete de python, puedes bajar un instalador de python de su [pagina oficial](https://www.python.org) , al abrir el instalador deberás marcar una opción que diga "Add Python x.x to PATH"

En caso de que sepas que tienes el interprete de python pero no te reconoce el comando python tendras que agregarlo manualmente como una variable de sistemas, [aquí](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/python-no-se-reconoce-como-un-comando-interno-o-externo/) hay una guía de los pasos a seguir para hacerlo.

Comment: Igual los pasos sería mejor agregarlos aqui y solo dejar el enlace como referencia

Comment: hola lo descargue con la versión 2.7 pero sigue con el mismo error

Comment: No se sobre la compatibilidad de la extensión de VC de Python para la versión 2.7 , te recomiendo que descargues una versión de python 3.x, y vuelvas a intentarlo (deberás estar pendiente de la compatibilidad de con tu sistema operativo, especialmente si usas windows) para no perder tiempo descargando instaladores que no te servirán

Comment: si tengo un windows 7 y la version 3.x no es compatible

Comment: en este momento estoy usando windows 7 y tengo python 3.8.9, es la ultima versión de python 3.x disponible para esta versión de windows. link: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-389/